# How to set font size, family and colour of listview in ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have the following ListView1

[asp.net]

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            onprerender="ListView1_PreRender" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

To which I have tried to set the following properties through CSS

[css]

```
#ListView1
{
    color: White;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

But that did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runat='server'` will change element IDs often times, appending the name of the class of the page. You can do two things to fix the issue:

1) Change the name of the ID selector in CSS to match what the ID is altered to be (which you figure out by doing a view source on the rendered page).

2) Apply a class to the element instead of using the ID.

The second one is probably better, as you can reuse that class on other pages without changing any CSS, and it's a bit more straightforward.

Comment: @ Sheep Slapper Thank you the first method worked:) It says I can accept the answer in 6 minutes so I will do so:)

Comment: Also is it possible to remove the column headers on the listview1?

Comment: @user2309648 Yes, you use the HeaderStyle attribute of the ListView. Check out MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.headerstyle.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `ClientIdMode` to static to ensure that the ID of the server control doesn't change when it is rendered as html even if it is in a container or a master page.

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            onprerender="ListView1_PreRender" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ClientIdMode="Static">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.cssclass%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property

```
.ListView1
{
    color: White;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

and then use it as

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            onprerender="ListView1_PreRender"  CssClass= "ListView1"
            onselectedindexchanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

You can style it more better if you use the ItemTemplate / LayoutTemplate as shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ottzkdTi2s)